# Program and Run PIC18 with pickit4 on linux

Tags: pic18, mplab-5.45

I am on linux ubuntu and target is a PIC18F47J53.
I basically want to program the chip and then let it run, using command lines and using pickit4.
using ipecmd (from mplab x ide v5.45), this is my command:

```
/opt/microchip/mplabx/v5.45/sys/java/zulu8.40.0.25-ca-fx-jre8.0.222-linux_x64/bin/java -jar /opt/microchip/mplabx/v5.45/mplab_platform/mplab_ipe/ipecmd.jar -TPPK4 /P18F47J53 -M -F"/path_to_myfile.hex" -W
```

This is my output

```
    DFP Version Used : PIC18F-J_DFP,1.4.41,Microchip
*****************************************************
Connecting to MPLAB PICkit 4...
Currently loaded versions:
Application version............00.06.66
Boot version...................01.00.00
Script version.................00.04.17
Script build number............db473af2f4
Tool pack version .............1.6.961
PICkit 4 is supplying power to the target (3.25 volts).
Target device PIC18F47J53 found.
Device Revision Id  = 0x1
*****************************************************
Calculating memory ranges for operation...
Erasing...
The following memory area(s) will be programmed:
program memory: start address = 0x0, end address = 0x3ff
program memory: start address = 0x1fc00, end address = 0x1fff7
configuration memory
Programming/Verify complete
 Program Report
30-Jan-2021, 12:54:41
Device Type:PIC18F47J53
Program Succeeded.
Operation Succeeded
```

All good, and takes about 12 seconds, however, after that the pickit4 turns off the power target, and the pickit LED is BLUE (I guess state "ready")

The main question is how can I let the pickit4 powering the boards? any specific parameter? (I cannot find on the readme.html)

If I use MPLAB X IPE GUI to program, the programming is much quicker (3 or 4 seconds), the pickit LED is YELLOW and the target is left powered on. (I selected "release from reset")
I have tried to get the log out with as many details as possible, but I cannot see the commands sent to the pickit4.

Any idea? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I realize that it's been a while since you asked, but i put the answer here for anyone who needs it. Add `-OL` to your command line options.

Comment: Can you offer an explanation of what the `-OL` parameter does and why it solves the problem?